# Restore mongodump database backup, which is the right flow?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I'm performing my first steps with MongoDB but still lost. I have read the docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) but I'm not able to find the the right steps in order to import|restore the DB. I have a .tgz file and I have uncompressed it. The output of `ll` command is as follow:

```
# ll rs-ds035698_2015-09-21T050031.000Z
total 208
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001   4096 Sep 21 01:00 admin
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   1037 Sep 21 01:01 oplog.bson
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001  20480 Sep 21 01:01 pdone
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001  20480 Sep 21 01:01 pdone_demo
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001   4096 Sep 21 01:00 pdone_demo_master
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001   4096 Sep 21 01:01 pdone_master
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 150589 Sep 21 01:01 rs-ds035698_2015-09-21T050031.000Z.log
```

I need to restore just pdone database. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it will helpful to you....

```
$mongorestore (It will restore all databases from your dump folder)
```

Restore particular database from your "dump" folder :

```
$mongorestore --db employee  C:\Users\mongo\dump\employee (Here "employee" is new db name)
```

if you want to import an JSON file then follow this :

```
mongoimport -d students -c grades < grades.json
                     (or)    
mongoimport -d students -c grades < C:\Users\mongo\Download\grades.json

Note: here "students" is database name, "grades" is collection name.
```

Comment: I must doing something wrong, didn't work for me: `$mongorestore --db rs-ds035698_2015-09-21T050031.000Z/pdone
connected to: 127.0.0.1
don't know what to do with file [dump]`

Comment: But `mongoimport` seems to be file by file and DB has a lot of collections or I am wrong?

Comment: the file your trying to import is in .json format or not...? @ReynierPM

Comment: Was my bad *I need to restore just pdone database* I've fixed the main post, is the complete DB not a collection

Comment: Sorry dude i can't get you............ if "pdone" is ur database folder then try this.....  mongorestore --db <your db name> <path of your db folder>. Eg:(mongorestore --db pdone /home/nani/Desktop/pdone) @ReynierPM

Answer (score 0):

Following command is useful for restoring mongodump BSON file. In my case it is user.bason file

```
sudo mongorestore -d ibfs -c log /opt/backup/mongodump-2017-02-01/ibfs/user.bson
```

Explaination :

```
sudo mongorestore -d ibfs(DATABASE_NAME) -c log(COLLECTION_NAME) /opt/backup/mongodump-2017-02-01/ibfs/user.bson(WHOLE PATH)
```